# ImageMagickObject with .Net

Tags: .net, vb.net, imagemagick

Still trying to resolve some image manipulation issues in .Net and I've come across ImageMagickObject.dll mentioned with some .Net projects - is this something usable with an application rather than a website? I have an .net application I'm trying to bridge with ImageMagick or one of its wrappers but not having much luck as my C/C++ skills are fairly limited.

ETA: My need is to use one of the similarity functions present in IM, IsSimilarImage() within the Image class or Compare's SimilarityImage(). I'm very confused as to whether these can be used in a non-command line context or not.

Thanks,
Becky

Comment: What is your specific need? You say it is possible with ImageMagick but not the wrapper classes? Could you be more specific?

Comment: Where you able to solve the above issue.

Comment: No, I switched to Aforge as it has a fairly reliable alternative similarity analysis function.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the dll that you are referring to but if you want to use ImageMagick from .NET it is probably easiest to use the wrapper library available at Codeplex:

> [**ImageMagick.NET**](http://imagemagick.codeplex.com/)

ImageMagick is a very powerful library for image manipulation that of course can be used in web applications and desktop applications as well.

Comment: I've had a look at this before but the information available is very sparse as the ImageMagick functionality I need isn't in the ImageMagick.Net library already and I can't work out how to extend it without documentation.

Answer (score 0):

ImageMagickObject is an optional COM component during install of ImageMagick. It takes arguments in the same form as the command line variants of the methods it provides (`Compare`, `Mogrify`, `Convert`, `Identify`, etc).

So if you just need a simplistic answer to image similarity and `compare.exe` from the command line gives you acceptable values, then this might be a very good solution for an in-process solution in your code.

As a disclaimer, however, I've run into some hiccups with [certain commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4925189/redirect-stderr-output-from-com-object-wrapper-in-net).